# Windows command prompt log to a file

Tags: windows, cmd

I'd like to easily save the log of the Windows command prompt into a file. Is there any alternative to select everything and right-click on copy?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can redirect the output of a cmd prompt to a file using `>` or `>>` to append to a file.

i.e.

```
echo Hello World >C:\output.txt
echo Hello again! >>C:\output.txt
```

or

```
mybatchfile.bat >C:\output.txt
```

Note that using `>` will automatically overwrite the file if it already exists.

You also have the option of redirecting stdin, stdout and stderr.

See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) for a complete list of options.

Answer (score 12):

**First method**

For Windows 7 and above users, Windows PowerShell give you this option. Users with windows version less than 7 can download PowerShell online and install it.

Steps:

1. type PowerShell in search area and click on "Windows PowerShell"
2. If you have a .bat (batch) file go to step 3 OR copy your commands to a file and save it with .bat extension (e.g. file.bat)
3. run the .bat file with following command

   `PS (location)> <path to bat file>/file.bat | Tee-Object -file log.txt`

This will generate a log.txt file with all command prompt output in it. Advantage is that you can also the output on command prompt.

**Second method**

You can use file redirection (>, >>) as suggest by [Bali C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799586/bali-c) above.

I will recommend first method if you have lots of commands to run or a script to run. I will recommend last method if there is only few commands to run.

Comment: NB: The second method is for the Visual Basic command window, not Windows Command Prompt

Comment: @Kidburla- No, file redirection using `<` or `>>` work on the Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: is there a trick so that it can self-limit the size of the file.. I mean say let the log be 1mb, no more... so only at max. the most recent 1mb of lines is ever stored at one time?

Answer (score 1):

In cmd when you use > or >> the output will be only written on the file. Is it possible to see the output in the cmd windows and also save it in a file. 
Something similar if you use teraterm, when you can start saving all the log in a file meanwhile you use the console and view it (only for ssh, telnet and serial).