# script like logging utility for windows

Tags: unix, powershell, logging, console, windows-console

Linux systems provide a nice tool (script) that can log terminal stdout data in a file. It has the following format:

To turn on logging: `script [options] [filename]`

To turn off logging: `exit`

I'm looking for an identical utility for windows console and powershell (Or any native windows support for logging the entire session).

Note: Please don't suggest [redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500616/windows-command-prompt-log-to-a-file).

Comment: In a powershell prompt type: Get-Help Start-Transcript -detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Start-Transcript](http://ss64.com/ps/start-transcript.html).

Keep in mind: It won't work in the ISE.  Don't forget Stop-Transcript at the end of your script!

Comment: Thank you so much.:) But, is there any solution for windows console?

Comment: To answer your question Shakil, there is no way to do this in the native command console.